# Linq to Entities query really slow. What can I do?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this Linq-to-Entities query using C#.

```
var query = from a in dbc.AcopioVias
            join b in dbc.Comunas on a.IdComuna equals b.Id
            join c in dbc.TipoViaCorrectoes on a.IdTipoViaCorrecto equals c.Id
            join d in dbc.ViaCorrectoes on a.IdViaCorrecto equals d.Id
            join e in dbc.ViaIncorrectoes on a.IdViaIncorrecto equals e.Id
            where b.CodCut.Contains(cut)
               && e.NombreVia_I.Contains(posibleNombreVia)
            select new
                   {
                      c.TipoVia_C,
                      d.NombreVia_C
                   };

string tv = null;
string nv  = null;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    tv = item.TipoVia_C;
    nv = item.NombreVia_C;
}
```

My problem, it is very slow. I need to query for every record, it could be 900.000 records!. And for every record I need to query.

What can I do to get more speed in my query?

Thank you very much!

Comment: why do you need to query for every record?

Comment: instead of explicit joins, add foreign keys. this will improve SQL performance, and allow you to do `a.Comunas`, etc. Also, try `ToList()`ing the query so it executes once.

Comment: Well, I dont know if I need to query for every record. This is how I know to do this. I think uploading all my records to my database it could be better, but I dont have to do this for permissions. If you know how to do this using a better way... Thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure that linq is playing any part in this issue. Have you tried seeing what SQL is generated from the expression? It may be slow regardless of using linq or not using linq.

Comment: I agree with @James.  You should start by profiling the resulting SQL query.

Comment: Why are you doing the foreach? Do you just need to populate the tv and nv variables with the last item? If so just query for the last item instead of the whole list of items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up your query you should use compiled Query. The syntax is not really beautiful but it's efficient.

Here's how it works

1. You create a public static delegate Func method:
2. Then you define the value of your delegate by calling the Compile method of the CompiledQuery static class
3. Call your public static Func method like any other delegate method

Here's an example let's say you want to get a client name from an id, it will look like that

```
    public static Func<DataContext, int /*input type*/, string /*output type*/> GetId =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext db, int id) =>   
           from customer in  Db   
           where customer.id == id  
           select customer.name );  

    GetId(dataContext, CustomerId);
```

If you don't know the Func1  method  see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Here's some advanced tutorial about CompiledQuery see [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-X)